# Smooth color gradient with ColorFunction (pdf export)

Tags: plotting, color, pdf-format

I wanted to plot a 2d curve (a function of the variable $k$) whose color intensity should be given by another function of $k$. This is the code:

```
plot1=Plot[
    .1k^2+1.2,{k,0,4},
    PlotRange->{{0,4},{0,2.5}},
    ColorFunction ->  Function[k,Opacity[ LogisticSigmoid[3(k-1.5)]/2+.3, Blue]],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotPoints->2
]
```

The problem is that I need to export that as a pdf (or svg or eps or any vector graphics format), and when I do that I get this:
[image: screenshot of the pdf]

I inserted the `PlotPoints->2` option because without that it was even worse. I would like to have a smooth gradient on the curve, without rasterizing. Is it even possible?

For comparison this is the png export and this is how it should look like:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include complete code, with the definitions of all variables needed to run it, otherwise it is next to impossible to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I inserted some simple example functions to complete the code.

Comment: Try adding `ImageResolution -> 600` to your Export command. For example `Export["test.pdf", plot1, ImageResolution -> 600]`.

Comment: @MelaGo I realized that such option rasterizes the image and then renders into pdf, so it is no more vector graphics... I would like to keep the image in vector graphics.

Comment: It is not a vector graphic even when drawn on screen.  `ColorFunction` is implemented using `VertexColors`, and that requires a pixel shader.  Pixel shaders require a bitmap.  The same is true for a number of effects, like `HatchFilling`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I guess it is impossible to have a smoother gradient in pdf format right?